# Are there any applications of choice modelling to romantic relationships?

Tags: social-psychology

**Background:** I was at a talk today where the presenter discussed a study that involved a administering a couple of questions asking participants which of two people they would prefer as a relationship partner. To simplify things a little bit, in one example participants were asked whether they would prefer a rich ugly partner or a poor attractive partner.

This got me interested in whether anyone had extended this idea to a comprehensive [choice modelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_modelling) study. I.e., get a large number of participants to compare pairs of possible partners with different characteristics and estimate the utility of different characteristics.

**Question:**

- What if any journal articles have examined relationship partner preference using a choice modelling methodology?
- What were the main findings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Speed dating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_dating) seems to provide an ideal setting for the type of study you seek. There are several relevant papers (see References below and Google search [human mate preferences speed dating](http://www.google.com/#q=human+mate+preferences+speed+dating)).

There is no consensus among researchers, but here's a sampling of some of the supposed *findings*:

- Buston & Emlen claim that people choose mates from their league, i.e., those they think have comparable traits, which lie in four categories: "wealth and status, family commitment, physical appearance, and sexual ﬁdelity".
- Todd et al. claim support for [parental investment theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parental_investment) because "men chose women based on their physical attractiveness, whereas women ... chose men whose overall desirability as a mate matched the women's self-perceived physical attractiveness"

> #### References
>
> - Buston, P. M. & Emlen, S. T. (2003) Cognitive processes underlying human mate choice: the relationship between self-perception and mate preference in Western society. PNAS 100: 8805-8810. [[pdf](http://www.pnas.org/content/100/15/8805.full.pdf)]
> - Todd, P. M., Penke, L., Fasolo, B., & Lenton, A. P. (2007) Different cognitive processes underlie human mate choices and mate preferences. PNAS 104: 15011-15016. [[pdf](http://www.pnas.org/content/104/38/15011.full.pdf)]